# Where can I get Goerli Test Ether? Can someone provide me with some? Thank you very much!

Tags: ether, cpp-ethereum, goerli

My address is: 0xDA866378188C6C455C6f624353cF5d3475484e4e

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Goerli Faucet](https://goerlifaucet.com/) powered by Alchemy.